# @RequestMapping with @PathVariable URI is different

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

hi i have a problem i am learnig how to pass values with PathVariable, i have a form with a input text and a button when you press the buttom it takes you to other page and show the value but it dont work when i press the buttom it takes me to this URL:

> `http://localhost:8080/appThyme/shoForm1.html?firstname=MyName&submit=`

and i get this error `HTTP 404 - /appThyme/showForm1.html`

but if i put this URL: `http://localhost:8080/appThyme/respuesta/Myname` it works it shows me my page with my name, how can i make that work with only pressing the buttom, why when i press the buttom it add question marks and equals symbols to my URI

```
 @Controller
 public class HomeController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/form1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showFormulario2(Model model) {
    logger.info("***PAG formulario***");
    return "form1.html";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/showForm1/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model, @PathVariable("id") String id) 
{
    String theId= id;
    model.addAttribute("TheID", theId);     
    return "showForm1.html";
}
```

my form1.html page

```
<form id="guestForm" th:action="@{/showForm1.html}"  method="get">
 <div>
     <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"></input> 
 </div>

 <div>
     <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

my showForm1.html page

```
enter code here 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
 <body>
<h1>
  Hello world!  
</h1>

 <P>  The value is  ${nombre} </P>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you put `th:action="@{/showForm1.html}"` ? How should that be handled?

Comment: i put that beacuse i am using thymeleaf view resolver and that "th" tag and annotation is necesary but i have the same problem if i use a normal view resolver with a normal "action=" tag

Comment: Ok, forget about the action. Why did you use that **path**?

Comment: i just wanted to learn how to past values between pages with PathVariable and i wanted to know how to use it

Comment: Read what you put in that `RequestMapping`. It doesn't match the URL you posted. And you probably need a query parameter instead of a path variable if you're wanting to submit from a form.

Comment: i know how to do it with a @RequestParam, but why it shows me this
URI: ´http://localhost:8080/appThyme/shoForm1.html' firstname=MyName&submit=´ instead of ´http://localhost:8080/appThyme/showForm1/Myname´

Comment: Because that's what you put as your `<form>`'s `action` value...

Answer (score 0):

Form submissions are not intended to work with the @PathVariable construct you are using here. @PathVariable is intended for use with REST-style URI's, and that is not what is generated on a form submit.

If you change your controller signature to look like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/showForm1.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Model model, @RequestParam("firstname") String id) 
{
    String theId= id;
    model.addAttribute("TheID", theId);     
    return "showForm1.html";
}
```

then the method should be called correctly on form submission.